# In a fragment,when an image is set as the background of a RelativeLayout in ScrollView, the RelativeLayout is misbehaving

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have an activity with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity" />
```

Then I have this fragment layout, which I am transacting in the fragment_container of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_login">


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The drawable bg_login is: [image: bg_login]
But the strange thing that is happening is, the background image(bg_login) hides all the content in RelativeLayout, in the preview pane as well as when I run the app. I can't find out why this is happening! Please help.

Comment: try adding background to image view and set relative over it using frame layout

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to do, are you want have multiple background in relative layouts when scrolled or not.
But i assuming you, the scroll view when have a children element with background is not best practice.
So scoll view must set to a children from parent have a background for good practice.
This may be can help you :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_login">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```